# Custom Authentication without username/password

Tags: java, rest, authorization, token

I'm developing a web application (Back end : JAVA/ stateless REST API) (Front end : Angular) which eventually be placed inside another web application.(let's say parent app).
The parent app which is session based handles authentication by username/password and create token for each user. Once a user is able to login the parent application he or she should also able to access my application. It is good to mention the token can also be used to retrieve user data by a SOAP call from my application.

My idea is to get this token with my front end component and send it to my REST Api. I'm going to keep those tokens inside a concurrent hash map and for each call coming from FE I'll check the token on BE for authorization. I wonder if it is a correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

When the parent app's session expires or the user logs out is the token invalidated?

If yes, how does your app know the token was invalidated?  Is that the **check the token on the BE**?  (which would need to be done for every request)

If a shared session is not an option then your approach is reasonable.

Also, for security the REST calls should always be HTTPS (refuse the request if not), and consider passing the token in a header instead of on the URL as a query parameter.